# Saving Fragment state

Tags: android, android-fragments

Here I am trying to save my fragment state. But i am getting a null pointer exception 
while saving the state.Can any help please Thanks.
I have pasted the code and error for reference

**List_View_Fragment.java**

```
package com.example.testfragment;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class List_View_Fragment extends Fragment {

    ListView list;
    EditText et;
    EditText_Adapter aa;
    ArrayList<String> Items;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//      if(savedInstanceState != null){
//          Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "save instance is not null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       
//      }

    };

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Items = new ArrayList<String>();
        Items.add("");
        Items.add("");
        Items.add("");
        Items.add("");
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, container, false);
        list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.MyList);

        if (aa == null) {
            aa = new EditText_Adapter(view.getContext(),
                    R.layout.list_view_edit_text, Items);
        }

        list.setAdapter(aa);
        return view;
    }
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        List_View_Fragment lf = (List_View_Fragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        **List_View_Fragment.SavedState myFragmentState = getFragmentManager().saveFragmentInstanceState(lf);
        outState.putParcelable("key", myFragmentState);**



    };


}
```

**Errors**

```
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080): java.lang.StackOverflowError
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.Fragment.performSaveInstanceState(Fragment.java:1840)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1578)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentInstanceState(FragmentManager.java:590)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at com.example.testfragment.List_View_Fragment.onSaveInstanceState(List_View_Fragment.java:51)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.Fragment.performSaveInstanceState(Fragment.java:1840)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1578)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentInstanceState(FragmentManager.java:590)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at com.example.testfragment.List_View_Fragment.onSaveInstanceState(List_View_Fragment.java:51)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.Fragment.performSaveInstanceState(Fragment.java:1840)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1578)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentInstanceState(FragmentManager.java:590)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at com.example.testfragment.List_View_Fragment.onSaveInstanceState(List_View_Fragment.java:51)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.Fragment.performSaveInstanceState(Fragment.java:1840)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1578)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentInstanceState(FragmentManager.java:590)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at com.example.testfragment.List_View_Fragment.onSaveInstanceState(List_View_Fragment.java:51)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.Fragment.performSaveInstanceState(Fragment.java:1840)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1578)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentInstanceState(FragmentManager.java:590)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at com.example.testfragment.List_View_Fragment.onSaveInstanceState(List_View_Fragment.java:51)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.Fragment.performSaveInstanceState(Fragment.java:1840)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1578)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentInstanceState(FragmentManager.java:590)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at com.example.testfragment.List_View_Fragment.onSaveInstanceState(List_View_Fragment.java:51)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.Fragment.performSaveInstanceState(Fragment.java:1840)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1578)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentInstanceState(FragmentManager.java:590)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at com.example.testfragment.List_View_Fragment.onSaveInstanceState(List_View_Fragment.java:51)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.Fragment.performSaveInstanceState(Fragment.java:1840)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1578)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentInstanceState(FragmentManager.java:590)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at com.example.testfragment.List_View_Fragment.onSaveInstanceState(List_View_Fragment.java:51)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.Fragment.performSaveInstanceState(Fragment.java:1840)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1578)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentInstanceState(FragmentManager.java:590)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at com.example.testfragment.List_View_Fragment.onSaveInstanceState(List_View_Fragment.java:51)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.Fragment.performSaveInstanceState(Fragment.java:1840)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1578)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentInstanceState(FragmentManager.java:590)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at com.example.testfragment.List_View_Fragment.onSaveInstanceState(List_View_Fragment.java:51)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.Fragment.performSaveInstanceState(Fragment.java:1840)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1578)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentInstanceState(FragmentManager.java:590)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at com.example.testfragment.List_View_Fragment.onSaveInstanceState(List_View_Fragment.java:51)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.Fragment.performSaveInstanceState(Fragment.java:1840)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1578)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentInstanceState(FragmentManager.java:590)
06-17 11:37:56.235: E/AndroidRuntime(31080):    at com.example.testfrag
```

Comment: highlight your `List_View_Fragment.java:51` please in order to see the error.

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop in your code, I am not sure why but it seems that calling to

```
  List_View_Fragment.SavedState myFragmentState = getFragmentManager().saveFragmentInstanceState(lf)
```

is provoking this behaviour. I'd recommend you to remove this line and to save the state of your views (TextViews, EditText, etc.) And in your `onActivityCreated` method (inside your fragment) restore the values of these elements.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You should use setRetainInstance(true).